# Angular material .mat-icon-button class not present in style section in index.html

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am adding a mat-button in my angular component,

```
<button mat-button class="toggle-button-navbar mat-icon-button" fxHide.lt-sm> 
    ​<mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>  ​
</button>
```

The button is showing. I expect the .mat-icon-button css class to be included in a  section in the index.html. But it is not there. I am following a working example which does have the .mat-icon-button css class in an  section of the served index.html file (not in the styles.bundle.css file). In that working example, when I inspect the element, the .mat-icon-button css class shows as:

```
.mat-icon-button {
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I found out that this css class is packed in MatButton.decorators in the @angular/material/bundles/materical-button.umd.js file. However, I could not figure out how this css class showing up in the index.html of the working example, but not showing up in my index.html.

Comment: Did you import the MatIconModule ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simply Import the `MatButtonModule` to solve this.
Make sure you also imported the `MatIconModule`.

Angular has to known that the `mat-button` attribute and the `<mat-icon>` tag.

The `mat-button` attribute applies a component. To register the component you have to import the `MatButtonModule` Module, which declares the `mat-button` component.

The `<mat-icon>` tag is a component. To register the mat-icon component you have to import the `MatIconModule` Module, which declares the component. This will create the mat-icon component and import the css rules.

To solve your Problem add following Code to your Module:

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
  ],
...
```

For more Information about the mat-icon Module see:
https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api

For more Information about Component registration in Angular see:
https://angular.io/guide/architecture

Comment: Thank you Raynigon. It is MatButtonModule missing.

Comment: if it was "MatIconModule" missing, he'd have had a runtime exception. As Charles Ju sais, it is "MatButtonModule"